# How get the latest process definition of camunda irrespective of a process instance

Tags: java, camunda, business-process-management

I'm trying to get the latest process definition to perform various operations irrespective of any specific process. I also wanted to migrate my existing processes to the latest definition. Can someone guide me for the same? Docs are not of much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query deployed process definitions using the RepositoryService (assuming you are using the java api):

```
repositoryService.createProcessDefinitionQuery()
    .latestVersion()
    .processDefinitionKey("myProcess")
    .singleResult();
```

For process instance migration, you can create and execute MigrationPlans:

```
MigrationPlan migrationPlan = processEngine.getRuntimeService()
   .createMigrationPlan("exampleProcess:1", "exampleProcess:2")
   .mapActivities("assessCreditWorthiness", "assessCreditWorthiness")
   .mapActivities("validateAddress", "validatePostalAddress")
   .mapActivities("archiveApplication", "archiveApplication")
   .build();
```

as documented [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/user-guide/process-engine/process-instance-migration/#process-instance-migration-by-example). There is also a [community extension](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-migration) for instance migration , which is a bit outdated, but at least should give you some ideas how to work with the API.

Comment: Excellent but what if i skip the process definition key? It works just fine without it. Does the key hasany significance?

Comment: I assumed you wanted the latest version of a particular service. If you need all, leave out the key and use list() instead of singleResult()